# Facebook doesn't see OG tags. Another socials works correct

Tags: facebook

I stucked at this problem. Facebook debuger tool doesn't see my og tags. Page source code has OG tags and all other socials works correctly. Could anybody help me?
Page contains all must have OG tags

```
<meta property="og:url" content="*URL*">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="*SITENAME*">
<meta property="og:title" content="*TITLE*">
<meta property="og:description" content="*DESCR*">
<meta property="og:image" content="*IMAGE_URL*">
```

Comment: you are basically telling us "it does not work", without any relevant info to help you. it is like telling a mechanic that your care does not work, on the phone, without any details, and you expect him to tell you what's wrong ;)

Comment: @luschn i edited post. Sry

Comment: i am afraid that does not tell us more about the issue at hand. a test link would be a good idea, else we can only guess.

Comment: @luschn https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Flada.uz%2Fnews%2Fauto_utilization.htm Page contains necessary og tags, but Facebook doesn't see them

Comment: "Can't validate SSL Certificate"

Comment: @luschn https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Flada.uz%2F this page also has this error but Facebook can see OG tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated new cert becase my old cert had some issues with CHAIN. After this Facebook saw all OG tags.